# Angular JS how to watch "Only One Property"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an array of objects with multiple editable properties.

** Update

For example the object

```
var objA = {
   propA:'vala',
   propB:'valb',
   propC:'valc',
   propD:'vald'
}
```

and array

```
var a1 = [objA,objA,objA,objA,objA.... ]
```

I would like to perform a separate action when each of these properties in objA change. It tried deep watch but it returns the old array and new array. Which means that i have to implement logic for change detection.

I am pretty sure i am missing something, as there are lot more efficient way of doing this in other frameworks. Is there any angular way of doing it efficiently ?

Comment: So why don't you `$scope.$watch('objA.propA', fn(propA){...})` and/or `$scope.$watch('objA.propB', fn(propB){...})`?

Comment: i just refined the question. Sorry about the confusion. I want to watch array and be notified of the changes :)

Comment: There is no such thing as "deep watch" - you can watch by value or reference.  How exactly do other frameworks do this "more efficiently"?  Ember's `get` and `set` methods don't make this problem any simpler to solve. I doubt there are any easier ways than the answer below for watching a dynamic number of properties on an object that can be replicated any number of times (at least with the information you have supplied).

Comment: Contrary to what others have suggested you can do this in angular by passing the watch method a javascript notation string that will be evaluated on the scope, and in your case you would just need to dynamically generate that string (and your watchers) in a loop. Alternatively you could do it by passing a function to the watcher which returns a reference to your properties. See my answer for examples of both methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var watcher = function(nv, ov, scope) {
  var props = Object.keys(nv);
  for (var i = props.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var prop = props[i];
    if (nv[prop] !== ov[prop])
      console.log('%s prop has been changed!', prop);  
  }
}

$scope.$watch('objA', watcher, true);
```

If values of your object are not primitive javascript types you can utilize `angular.equals` function for comparison.

Comment: That is exactly what i am trying to avoid. Too many line for something that angular should do.

Comment: smehnawal why should angular do this for you? efficiency doesn't really have to do with a framework providing something for you or not it's a matter of resource usage and depends on the algorithm being used and how that is actually processed based on a processor architecture, javascript interpreter and all the layers in between.  If this solution solves the problem you should accept it, if it causes such a performance bottleneck then you can ask for a more efficient version of the algorithm by showing in tests that it is too slow.

Comment: I think i have to give in to this solution. But still i think it is a very basic concept and framework should be able to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

It is not well documented in angular, but there are at least two ways to do what you are asking.

**Method 1: Pass a notated string**

You can use $watch to drill down to a single property by using javascript notation as a string, like this:

```
$scope.$watch('objA.propA', function(newVal, oldVal){
   // do something
});
```

As long as the string you pass can be evaluated at the scope level, it will work. Since your objects are stored in an array on your scope, you would need to either manually path out to them, or dynamically create the paths in a loop. For example:

```
$scope.$watch("a1[1].propA", function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // do something
});
$scope.$watch("a1[1].propB", function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // do something
});
$scope.$watch("a1[2].propA", function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // do something
});
$scope.$watch("a1[2].propB", function(newVal, oldVal) {
   // do something
});
// etc...
```

OR...

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.a1.length; i++) {
   $scope.$watch("a1[" + i + "].propA", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      // do something
   });
   $scope.$watch("a1[" + i + "].propB", function(newVal, oldVal) {
      // do something
   });
   // etc...
}
```

That all being said... You may end up adding a LOT of watches with this method. There may be a performance impact.

You can see a working plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QJHxXTJX9HYV8BmbddyR?p=preview

**Method 2: Pass a function**

Alternatively, you could iterate on your array and pass a function to the watch that references the properties directly, like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < $scope.a1.length; i++) {

   $scope.$watch(function() {
     return $scope.a1[i].propA;
   }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
     // references a1[i].propA
   });

   $scope.$watch(function() {
     return $scope.a1[i].propB;
   }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
     // references a1[i].propB
   });

   $scope.$watch(function() {
     return $scope.a1[i].propC;
   }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
     // references a1[i].propC
   });

   $scope.$watch(function() {
     return $scope.a1[i].propC;
   }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
     // references a1[i].propC
   });
}
```

Once again, watch your performance.